# ThreadSanitizer deadlock not detected and no result at the end (du to the deadlocked program)

Tags: c, pthreads, clang, deadlock, thread-sanitizer

I would like to know where is a deadlock with the thread sanitizer (clang) but the problem is that the program is blocked and the deadlock is not detected during the compilation with -fsanitize=thread option. And there no result at the end of the execution cuz the program is blocked (impossible to quit the program due to the deadlock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program is already blocked you don't need ThreadSanitizer to debug it. You can attach to a deadlocked process with gdb and see all threads stacktraces with `thread apply all bt`. You should see attempts to lock the same mutex from different threads in `thread apply all bt` output.